# Best text searching logic on PHP and MySql index

Tags: php, mysql, json, indexing, innodb

Trying to design a indexing and searching system for my CMS.

What I had done till now is :

Three columns in Database Table (POST table) (InnoDB - utf8mb4_unicode_ci).

1. Original content (JSON Format).
2. Tokens (Getting all text from JSON, removing stopwords and then saving tokens to that column), also enabling indexing on that column.
3. Tokens (directly coming from a tagging field, stackoverflow like tagging.), also indexing that field.

My CMS is working on that approach, but that increasing the index and table size due to tokens produced from original content.

Is there ant way to improve?

I am coming from JAVA background (was using Lucane). Its hard for me to make a dictionary of all stopword. If anybody know about pre made API os script for stopword removal.

Comment: Will [full-text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) work?

Comment: @AlonEitan that seems good, also support stopword removal, But i have still use second column because fist column contain JSON keys, which are not good for indexing,

Comment: Use a separate table with unique tags, and bridge it to your main table with a many to many relationship.  That way you normalize your data, and reduce it's size.  It also makes searching for tags much easier then you can use IN, instead of Match Against or wildcards, so you take full advantage of indexing.  It would also aid in creating things like an auto-complete on the tag search field etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `tag` system, like stack overflow or many other systems I would use 3 tables.

- The main table with your json
- A tags table
- A junction or bridge table for a many to many relationship.

With a separate tag table, you can search it using `IN` or just `=`.  You can use the table as an auto-complete.  You "normalize" your data, reducing it. etc... It does add a few Joins and a bit of complexity to the queries but I would say it's still fairly trivial.

Also I have written a Text input plugin in Jquery to recognize tags within a text field.  It's largely un-documented but your welcome to play around with it.

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/jQuery-Plugins/jqWall

It was for a small project where we needed a "twitter" like wall with hashtags,  so it can be setup to recognize and autocomplete as a user types tags that start with `#` for example.  Allowing a user to auto-complete text with the tags and reduce errors or misspelled tags from occurring.  You can define what you want to match and it has a few callback for other functionality.  It's pretty simple to use.

You can see in this fiddle the basic setup ( it's pretty standard Many To Many )

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2WSaLjtnuDrZE2CcVhAe9S/1

Some other functionality this gives you is for example this query.

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    tags AS t
LEFT JOIN
    posts_tags AS pt ON t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE
    pt.tag_id IS NULL;
```

Which will select all the tags not used in a post. As well as it's very easy to count how many posts have a given tag.

```
SELECT
    count(p.id) AS total
FROM
    posts AS p
JOIN
    posts_tags AS pt ON p.id = pt.post_id
JOIN
    tags AS t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE
    tag = 'Programming';
```

This might look complicated if your not used to how the relationships like this work and using Joins.  But consider counting how many posts have it when you have a list of keywords.  You will be using `keywords LIKE '%Java%'` and it will probably hurt your performance ( whenever you use `%word` preceding wildcards ).  Also of note is if you have keywords like `Javascript` you will count it with this query and `Java` is not at all like `Javascript` so it can be an impossible task to accurately count how many posts you have using partial string matches.

The only thing I would suggest if you do go with a single field is to use a delimiter, and include it to both the front and back of the contents so like this.

```
 |tag1|tag2|tag|tag10|
```

The reason for this is then you can include the delimiter in your search, consider this partial query

```
WHERE tag LIKE "%tag%"
```

Now if you search for that you would find all the tags, but because we have our delimiters, you can do this

```
WHERE tag LIKE "%|tag|%"
```

Which would limit the match.  But for it to work you need the delimiter at the start and end of the list.  consider this `tag1|tag10|tag` without those we can't match `|tag|` with `%|tag|%` so it all falls apart.  This would probably work `ok` for a system that has light use, but separate table are still superior, because of the nature of indexes and how they handle wild card searches.

```js
console.log("type any of these 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'Programming', 'PHP' and press enter to select from list, or use the mouse.");
console.log("press enter to simulate submission, logs contents.");

$('#test').jqWall({
  id: 'jqWall',
  autoComplete: {
    cache: ['Java', 'JavaScript', 'Programming', 'PHP'],
    match: /([^\s]+)$/, //$ ends with is required
    search : function(term, matches, callback){
        if(matches.lenght == 0){
        //get matches array from server by AJAX using `term`
        }
        callback( matches ); //requred
 
      },
  },
  submit : function(wrapper){
    //press enter to submit
    var contents = wrapper.find('textarea').val();
    //you could post contents back to server to save.
    console.log(contents);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ArtisticPhoenix/jQuery-Plugins/master/jQuery-Plugins/jqWall/jqWall.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/ArtisticPhoenix/jQuery-Plugins/master/jQuery-Plugins/jqWall/jqWall.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
  #jqWall textarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
  }
</style>


<div id="test" style=""></div>
```

Comment: i am using the same approach for tags, but according to you twist is garnating tags from input post text. after that there will be no need to index full POST (FULL TEXT index feature). am i right?

Comment: It will be hard to use your un-doc code, plz guide through the analysis process. like not recommending stopwords and useless words, recommend only useful and weight words

Comment: That's right you wouldn't have to do full text index.  I would use a `#` or similar if you allow them in the main body of text.   If you want to search on the main body, then I would just use full text.

Comment: LOL.  It wont be hard its only 600 lines of Javascript.

Comment: ok, but i already made a tag recommendation system with autocomplete suggestions, only difference is the "#".  i am talking about the process which will recommend tags from input post text without any "#" prefix in a word.

Comment: That's cool, it was just a suggestion.  Mine does tag location in real time in a textarea, so it needs something to distinguish tags from "normal" words.  The point, remains your data will be cleaner in a separate tags table, with them linked by Many To Many.

Comment: i think steps will involve a table with lot of good words with their weight. a javascript will compare the input text with that table and recommend the tags according to their weights, just like LUCENE, we only need learning data from somewhere for for that table

Comment: Ok, "needs #" is strong it can work without that as well.  Anyway that wasn't my point.  It was just a suggestion to help you.  Datawise I would recommend a separate table, but it depends on your use case.  That is not for me to judge.  I only offer the option.

Comment: thanks for the help, the most powerful use of "#" i think is Tags inside the Full POST text, like "I am #nothing here". user can easily identify the tags in a long text and click on it to read related posts, anyway again thanks bro

Comment: There I added a live demo of it, you can put in Java, Javascrip, Programming, PHP.  By default it changes the casing to lowercase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158750/discussion-between-lovepreet-singh-batth-and-artisticphoenix).

Comment: That's all right I've said my part.  I've done a lot of this kind of thing, and it may seem more complicated at first, but there are some things you just can't do when using a single table and a field full of keywords.

Comment: I dropped the idea of single table, also splitting JSON now into another table and will store HTML into field for faster reading

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe the two "tokens" columns, you need to have a `FULLTEXT` index on each.  And then use `MATCH(token1) AGAINST('+mysql +index IN BOOLEAN MODE)` to look for a posting that talks about both "mysql" and "index" (or indexes or indexing or indexed, etc).